# How to define "true" in a formal manner?

Tags: logic

Title says it all.

My understanding is that axiom system is a set of *true* propositions which are promises and self-evident. And to prove a proposition, we use deductive way to abbreviate as axioms or axiom based proved theorems or lemmas. From this view, I thought I could think *true* as axioms itself.

However, while I'm studying mathematical logic, the text book states *true* without introducing any axioms, but some definitions. They states; for every rule of the system, the following holds: whenever the elements are derivable in a system, they have the property $P$ which holds for every elements derived from a system. (Property $P$ defined as a function $P: X \rightarrow\{\text{true, false}\}$ where $X$ is a set of all strings. Iff the value is $\text{true}$, we say the element has the property $P$ in a system.)

Is this the definition of mathematical *true* and *falsity*?
If it's not, how to rigorously define *true*?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: See in *SEP* the entry on [Axiomatic Theories of Truth](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-axiomatic/)

Comment: An see also [Truth](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth/) with biblio and links to other relevant *SEP* entries.

Answer (score 3):

It is not so easy to assert that *all* axioms of *all* mathematical theories are "self-evident".

For sure, in mathematics, like all other sciences, "first principles" (i.e.axioms) are *assumed* to be *true* (until revision).

Logical *inference rules* are "designed" to be *sound*: i.e. to "transfer" truth.

Thus, deductive consequences of our axioms will be true, provided that the axioms are.

---

*Added*

If I understand your proposal, after the comments, you start from the set $Z$ of expressions (i.e.well-formed strings of symbols of the language) "generated" with a *system*; if we interpret *system* as a "typical" couple :

> *axioms* + *inference rules*,

the set $Z$ of all expressions "generated" with it is what we usually call the set of *theorems*.

Now you introduce the [*characteristic function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $Z$, i.e.:

> $P_Z(x)=1$ iff $x \in Z$.

Thus, your proposal is to "define" :

> > $T(x)$ [i.e. $x$ is *true*] iff $P_Z(x)=1$.

Assuming that my interpretation is correct, we have a couple of problems :

*(i)* [Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) applies to "significant" formal systems, including most of "interesting" mathematical ones :

> in any consistent formal system $F$ within which a certain amount of arithmetic can be carried out, there are statements of the language of $F$ which can neither be proved nor disproved in $F$.

Thus, according to our "natural" insights regarding *truth*, we have mathematical truths expressible in the system $F$ which are **not** provable in it, i.e.are the class of *theorems* of the system $F$ does not "exhaust" all the "true facts" of the system.

**(ii)** if your system is *inconsistent* it will "generate" as theorem *all* well-formed "expressions" of the language. Thus, the set $Z$ of *theorems* will be "too large".

Comment: I appreciate your answer and also perfectly agree with this. But it's not suitable answer for my question. I'm asking "is my understanding correct?" or "if it's not, how to rigorously define true?".

Comment: @ShinKim - Form Plato and Aristotle we are still struggling with the "definition" of *truth*; this, I simply do not think that you can have a "scientific" definition of it. About math logic, the usual def consider a *valuation* $v : X \rightarrow \{ true, false \}$, where $X$ is the set of atomic formulae. Then the usual semantic rules for *connectives* and *quantifiers* propagetes this definition to *all* well-formed formulas. Lastly, *inference rules* are designed in order to be *sound*, i.e.to derive *true* conclusions from *true* premises. Thus, if we start from *true* axioms ... 1/2

Comment: ... all *theorems* derived from them through correct applications of the infernce rules, are *true* either. 2/2

Comment: Let $\mathcal{A}^*$ denotes a set all strings, and let $Z$ be a set whose elements were generated by means of a system $\mathfrak{C}$. We define _property function_ $P_\mathfrak{C}:\mathcal{A}^*\rightarrow\{\text{true,false}\}$ iff $P_\mathfrak{C}(\zeta)=\text{true}$ where $\zeta\in Z$. Isn't this a "scientific definition"?